# Не работает switch (окончание слова, скрипт)

Tags: javascript

`введите сюда код`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YJrVJM

Подскажите, что в скрипте не так. Не ставится окончание в слово.

Comment: окончание вычисляется после алерта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var num = Number(prompt('Введите число:'));
var end = '';

switch (num) {
  case 1: end = "a"; break;
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4: end = "ы"; break;

}
alert('На ветке сидит ' + num + ' ворон' + end);
```

1. `prompt` возвращает вам строку, а в case вы проверяете число.
2. Выводить на нужно уже после всех действий с переменными